# Selection of Points or Series in MS Chart

Tags: c#, mschart

I am look at the System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart class, and I cannot figure out how to enable the selection of points or series (like in Excel charts). Is the functionality there, or do I have to implement it myself?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone in the future that is faced with the same problem and wants a quick answer/read, the below snippet of code does the trick:

```
ChartArea _chartarea;
Series _data;

private void Plot_MouseClick(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e)
    HitTestResult result = _plot.HitTest(e.X, e.Y);

    if (result.ChartElementType == ChartElementType.DataPoint && result.ChartArea == _chartarea && result.Series == _data)
    {
        // A point is selected.
    }
}
```